# ASP.NET Core 6 launchUrl equivalent for Production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel

I'm using the ASP.NET Core 6 weather forecast sample. In my development environment, I can run the app and it shows the "default" page as `localhost:xxxx/swagger/index.html`.

In production, the default doesn't show; I can access it if I use the full URL `https://example.com/swagger`

How do I get ASP.NET Core 6 (in production) to default to that page?

I have tried:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=swagger}");
});
```

It doesn't work either. Again the problem is with production. -- launchUrl works only in dev (by design)

Answer (score 0):

**launchSettings.json**

```
    "ProductionEnvironment": {
       //Some configuration...

       //add this
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
       }
     }
```

**Program.cs**

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();

}
//add Production Environment
else if (app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

When you add the above configuration, the app will show the "default" page as `localhost:xxxx/swagger/index.html` in Production.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue using the following code:

```
app.UseRouting(); 

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
    {
         context.Response.Redirect("swagger");

    });
});
```

It now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[Sam's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610043/16632594) worked but had a little issue because the async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. So it's better to consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Follow this example:

**Program.cs** or Startup.cs in older versions

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/", context => {
        context.Response.Redirect("swagger");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});
```